# how to display progress of file being sent over a python socket connection

Tags: python

I have recently created a python based sharing application that helps users share files from one computer to another on LAN. My question now is that, is there any way in which I am able to display the progress of file being sent to the client. NOTE: The connection in the whole process is being made using the socket module in python.

Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the serious issue

Comment: Split the file into multiple (binary) parts and send them over the socket. Then you can report on the progress with regard to the single bits (no pun intended).